# MySQL using variable in SELECT command with view affecting performance

Tags: mysql, optimization, mysql-5.7

sorry if this has been asked already. I've just moved from MySQL 5.6 to 5.7.17 and I'm struggling to understand this issue.

I have a view "delete_me_test_" which has around 26k rows.

```
SELECT 
    delete_me_test_.*
from delete_me_test_;
```

takes less than a second. However I'm trying to assign a value to a variable withing the select command. The goal is to reissue a row number to all returned rows which can be used by DataTable plugin(JQuery) from web-front-end.

To cut the story short, initializing or assigning a value withing a select command affects the performance drastically. I mean 10 seconds to return 50 rows.

This code here

```
SELECT 
    (select @row_nummer:= @row_nummer+1), -- this is just a test not final code
    delete_me_test_.*
from delete_me_test_;
```

takes around 10 seconds and please see the explain graph with and without using the variable for the same query.
[image: Without using variables]

[image: With using variables]

I'm still learning MySQL and not sure what exactly this issue could be but I can confirm this exact setup was working on 5.6 version without any issues. In 5.7 server gets 100% CPU usage and query never ends. Anyone could help on this please?

I must add this too: If I extract the actual query from the "delete_me_Test" view and add the variable there to test

```
SELECT 
    (select @row_nummer:= @row_nummer+1),
    ...
    rest of the selct field statements
from many tables in the select command;
```

Query works as expected without any issue. Its just when I use it as a view it gets screwed.

I'm using MySQL on windows server 2008 with all updates are installed. Is this a bug?

**EDIT: Explain of above query with variable assigned**

```
+---+---------+-------------------------------+--+--------+---------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------+-----+----------------------------------------------------------------+--------+--------+--------------------------+
| 1 | PRIMARY |          <derived2>           |  | system |                                                   |                                              |     |                                                                |   1    | 100.00 |                          |
+---+---------+-------------------------------+--+--------+---------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------+-----+----------------------------------------------------------------+--------+--------+--------------------------+
| 1 | PRIMARY | <derived3>                    |  | ALL    |                                                   |                                              |     |                                                                | 222724 | 100.00 |                          |
| 3 | DERIVED | tbl_su                        |  | ALL    |                                                   |                                              |     |                                                                |  26712 | 100.00 |                          |
| 3 | DERIVED | tbl_su_os_sub                 |  | eq_ref | PRIMARY,sub_status_id_UNIQUE                      | sub_status_id_UNIQUE                         |   4 | ccmsv2.tbl_su.suOperationStatusID                              |      1 | 100.00 |                          |
| 3 | DERIVED | tbl_su_os_main                |  | eq_ref | PRIMARY,idtbl_OperatonStatusMain_UNIQUE           | PRIMARY                                      |   4 | ccmsv2.tbl_su_os_sub.main_status_id                            |      1 | 100.00 |                          |
| 3 | DERIVED | tbl_su_requested_region       |  | eq_ref | PRIMARY,regionID_UNIQUE,regionID                  | PRIMARY                                      |   4 | ccmsv2.tbl_su.tbl_SU_requested_Region                          |      1 | 100.00 |                          |
| 3 | DERIVED | tbl_su_maritalstatus          |  | eq_ref | PRIMARY,maritalStatusID_UNIQUE                    | PRIMARY                                      |   4 | ccmsv2.tbl_su.suMaritalStatusID                                |      1 | 100.00 |                          |
| 3 | DERIVED | tbl_su_gender                 |  | eq_ref | PRIMARY,gender_ID_UNIQUE                          | PRIMARY                                      |   4 | ccmsv2.tbl_su.suGender                                         |      1 | 100.00 |                          |
| 3 | DERIVED | tbl_su_sectionandcategory     |  | eq_ref | SectionAndCatID_UNIQUE                            | SectionAndCatID_UNIQUE                       |   4 | ccmsv2.tbl_su.suSectionAndCatID                                |      1 | 100.00 | Using where              |
| 3 | DERIVED | tbl_su_added_by               |  | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                           | PRIMARY                                      | 110 | ccmsv2.tbl_su.added_by_uuid                                    |      1 | 100.00 |                          |
| 3 | DERIVED | tbl_su_updated_by             |  | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                           | PRIMARY                                      | 110 | ccmsv2.tbl_su.updated_by_uuid                                  |      1 | 100.00 |                          |
| 3 | DERIVED | tbl_section_category          |  | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                           | PRIMARY                                      |   4 | ccmsv2.tbl_su_sectionandcategory.sectionCatID                  |      1 | 100.00 |                          |
| 3 | DERIVED | tbl_section                   |  | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                           | PRIMARY                                      |   4 | ccmsv2.tbl_su_sectionandcategory.sectionID                     |      1 | 100.00 |                          |
| 3 | DERIVED | tbl_oa_sub                    |  | ref    | fk_tbl_su_occupancyAgreement_sub_tbl_SU1_idx      | fk_tbl_su_occupancyAgreement_sub_tbl_SU1_idx | 110 | ccmsv2.tbl_su.uuid                                             |      1 | 100.00 |                          |
| 3 | DERIVED | tbl_property_room_bed         |  | eq_ref | PRIMARY,bedid_UNIQUE,bedid                        | bedid_UNIQUE                                 |   4 | ccmsv2.tbl_oa_sub.bed_id                                       |      1 | 100.00 |                          |
| 3 | DERIVED | tbl_property_room             |  | eq_ref | PRIMARY,roomID_UNIQUE,roomID                      | roomID_UNIQUE                                |   4 | ccmsv2.tbl_property_room_bed.RoomID                            |      1 | 100.00 |                          |
| 3 | DERIVED | tbl_property_room_floor       |  | eq_ref | PRIMARY,RoomFloorID_UNIQUE                        | PRIMARY                                      |   4 | ccmsv2.tbl_property_room.FloorID                               |      1 | 100.00 | Using where              |
| 3 | DERIVED | tbl_property                  |  | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                           | PRIMARY                                      | 110 | ccmsv2.tbl_property_room.property_uuid                         |      1 | 100.00 |                          |
| 3 | DERIVED | tbl_oa                        |  | eq_ref | PRIMARY,oA_ID_UNIQUE,Occupancyid                  | PRIMARY                                      |   4 | ccmsv2.tbl_oa_sub.oa_main_id                                   |      1 | 100.00 |                          |
| 3 | DERIVED | tbl_oa_occupancy_type         |  | eq_ref | PRIMARY,occypancyType_ID_UNIQUE                   | PRIMARY                                      |   4 | ccmsv2.tbl_oa.oA_typeID                                        |      1 | 100.00 | Using where              |
| 3 | DERIVED | tbl_oa_os_sub                 |  | eq_ref | PRIMARY,sub_status_id_UNIQUE                      | sub_status_id_UNIQUE                         |   4 | ccmsv2.tbl_oa.oA_OperationStatusID                             |      1 | 100.00 |                          |
| 3 | DERIVED | tbl_property_room_bed_status  |  | eq_ref | PRIMARY,bed_status_id_UNIQUE,bed_status_id        | PRIMARY                                      |   4 | ccmsv2.tbl_property_room_bed.statusID                          |      1 | 100.00 |                          |
| 3 | DERIVED | tbl_property_room_type        |  | eq_ref | PRIMARY,ID_UNIQUE                                 | PRIMARY                                      |   4 | ccmsv2.tbl_property_room.roomTypeID                            |      1 | 100.00 |                          |
| 3 | DERIVED | tbl_property_region           |  | eq_ref | PRIMARY,regionID_UNIQUE,regionID                  | PRIMARY                                      |   4 | ccmsv2.tbl_property.property_region_id                         |      1 | 100.00 |                          |
| 3 | DERIVED | tbl_oa_added_by               |  | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                           | PRIMARY                                      | 110 | ccmsv2.tbl_oa.oA_added_by_uuid                                 |      1 | 100.00 |                          |
| 3 | DERIVED | tbl_oa_updated_by             |  | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                           | PRIMARY                                      | 110 | ccmsv2.tbl_oa.oA_updated_by_uuid                               |      1 | 100.00 |                          |
| 3 | DERIVED | tbl_property_local_manager    |  | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                           | PRIMARY                                      | 110 | ccmsv2.tbl_property.local_manager_uuid                         |      1 | 100.00 |                          |
| 3 | DERIVED | tbl_property_regional_manager |  | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                           | PRIMARY                                      | 110 | ccmsv2.tbl_property.regional_manager_uuid                      |      1 | 100.00 |                          |
| 3 | DERIVED | tbl_su_os_middle              |  | eq_ref | PRIMARY,middle_status_id_UNIQUE                   | PRIMARY                                      |   4 | ccmsv2.tbl_su_os_sub.middle_status_id                          |      1 | 100.00 |                          |
| 3 | DERIVED | tbl_oa_os_middle              |  | eq_ref | PRIMARY,middle_status_id_UNIQUE                   | PRIMARY                                      |   4 | ccmsv2.tbl_oa_os_sub.middle_status_id                          |      1 | 100.00 |                          |
| 3 | DERIVED | tbl_property_landlord         |  | eq_ref | PRIMARY,uuid_UNIQUE                               | PRIMARY                                      | 110 | ccmsv2.tbl_property.landlord_uuid                              |      1 | 100.00 |                          |
| 3 | DERIVED | tbl_property_proposed_to      |  | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                           | PRIMARY                                      | 110 | ccmsv2.tbl_property.proposed_on_behalf_uuid                    |      1 | 100.00 | Using index              |
| 3 | DERIVED | tbl_property_proposed_by      |  | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                           | PRIMARY                                      | 110 | ccmsv2.tbl_property.proposed_by_uuid                           |      1 | 100.00 | Using index              |
| 3 | DERIVED | tbl_landlord_company          |  | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                           | PRIMARY                                      | 110 | ccmsv2.tbl_property_landlord.company_uuid                      |      1 | 100.00 | Using index              |
| 3 | DERIVED | tbl_oa_os_main                |  | eq_ref | PRIMARY,idtbl_OperatonStatusMain_UNIQUE           | PRIMARY                                      |   4 | ccmsv2.tbl_oa_os_sub.booking_main_status_id                    |      1 | 100.00 |                          |
| 3 | DERIVED | tbl_property_occupancy_type   |  | eq_ref | PRIMARY,occypancyType_ID_UNIQUE                   | PRIMARY                                      |   4 | ccmsv2.tbl_property.property_occupancy_typeID                  |      1 | 100.00 |                          |
| 3 | DERIVED | tbl_property_os_sub           |  | ref    | PRIMARY,propertyStatusID                          | PRIMARY                                      |   4 | ccmsv2.tbl_property.property_operation_statusID                |      1 | 100.00 | Using where; Using index |
| 3 | DERIVED | tbl_property_os_main          |  | eq_ref | PRIMARY,idtbl_property_operationStatusMain_UNIQUE | PRIMARY                                      |   4 | ccmsv2.tbl_property_os_sub.tbl_property_operationstatus_mainID |      1 | 100.00 | Using index              |
| 3 | DERIVED | <derived4>                    |  | ref    | <auto_key0>                                       | <auto_key0>                                  |   4 | ccmsv2.tbl_su.safeguarding_type_id                             |      2 | 100.00 |                          |
| 3 | DERIVED | <derived5>                    |  | ref    | <auto_key0>                                       | <auto_key0>                                  |   4 | ccmsv2.tbl_property.safeguarding_type_id                       |      2 | 100.00 |                          |
| 5 | DERIVED | tbl_safeguarding_type         |  | ALL    |                                                   |                                              |     |                                                                |     22 | 100.00 |                          |
| 4 | DERIVED | tbl_safeguarding_type         |  | ALL    |                                                   |                                              |     |                                                                |     22 | 100.00 |                          |
| 2 | DERIVED |                               |  |        |                                                   |                                              |     |                                                                |        |        | No tables used           |
+---+---------+-------------------------------+--+--------+---------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------+-----+----------------------------------------------------------------+--------+--------+--------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't do the extra `SELECT`, it is unnecessary.

```
SELECT 
    @row_nummer:= @row_nummer+1, -- this is just a test not final code
    delete_me_test_.*
from delete_me_test_;
```

A common technique for initializing the variable:

```
SELECT 
    @row_nummer:= @row_nummer+1, -- this is just a test not final code
    delete_me_test_.*
from delete_me_test_
JOIN ( SELECT @row_nummer := 0 );
```

My opinion on `VIEWs`:  Don't use them.  But if you want to discuss an issue with them, we need to see both the `CREATE VIEW` and the `CREATE TABLE` for the underlying table(s).  Also `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`.

Comment: Hi & thx for the input. It didn't help either. I've added the exlplain result above. If viewes aren't good idea whats the purpose of views and whats the alternative? I might well place new question when i feel so.

Comment: A `VIEW` cannot run faster than the underlying `SELECT`.  A `VIEW` can be used to hide thing from casual users, or to compensate for a schema change.

Comment: That's a long Explain!  Dig into the code and find what leads to the first 2 lines and the last 3.  They seem to be the worst; lets focus on them.